# How to customize IntelliJ provided values in my own annotations

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations

I'm studying Spring and when I use the `Scope` annotation for a class, IntelliJ helps me providing different options for `value` property (String), [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WxGB.png)

How can I develop my own annotation to predefine those values?

Also for the `@Value` annotation, where does IntelliJ get the values from? or is it just a "sharpening" for Spring?

Edit: This is meant specifically for annotations. In general, on the left as suggested in Spring, on the right is my class. How to do as on the left?

[image: Example for edit]

```
package ru.max.mypacktest;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyRealName {
    
    String value() default "";

}
```

Comment: Maybe the following link is a good beginning https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html

Comment: Could you show annotation definition?

Comment: Done, I've edited

Comment: That's the work of Spring bundled plugin, I don't think there's a quick and easy way to do same for custom annotations

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no default way to configure it but you can try using [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) feature as a workaround.

- Create the following Live Template:

  [image]

  [image]
- Call it in your code:

  [image]